# Placing labels for axes appropriately using "anchor=north west" in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have labels `x` and `y` for the axes on a `pgfplot`.  I use `anchor=north west` for positioning the `x` and `anchor=south west` for positioning the `y`.  I also use `axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt}` to extend the axes.  Apparently the `x` and `y` do not follow this extension.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\begin{document}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=axis_1, width=2.75in, height=2.75in, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2.5,xmax=2.5,
    ymin=-15.625,ymax=15.625,
    restrict y to domain=-15.625:15.625,
    xtick={\empty}, ytick={\empty},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[samples=251, domain=-2.5:2.5] {x^3)} node[right, pos=1, font=\footnotesize]{$y = x^{3}$};

\end{axis}

%Title for the plot of the cubing function illustrating a function with no absolute extrema is typeset.
\node[font=\bfseries, anchor=north, inner sep=0, align=center] at ($(axis_1.south) +(0,-0.5)$)
{\mbox{An illustration of a function with} \\
\mbox{no extrema}};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\qquad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=axis_2, width=2.75in, height=2.75in, axis on top,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-7,xmax=7, domain=-7:7,
    ymin=-1,ymax=1,
    restrict y to domain=-1:1,
    xtick={\empty},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
    ytick={-1,1},
    yticklabels={$-1$, 1},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501, domain=-6.28318:6.28318] {sin(deg(x))} node[anchor=south west, pos=0.6875,font=\footnotesize]{$y = \sin{x}$};

\end{axis}

%Title for the plot of the sine function illustrating a function with absolute extrema is typeset.
\node[font=\bfseries, anchor=north, inner sep=0, align=center] at ($(axis_2.south) +(0,-0.5)$)
{\mbox{An illustration of a function with} \\
\mbox{two extrema: \boldmath$-1$ and $1$\unboldmath}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?:

[image]

prolong of axes with `shorten >` doesn't move anchor of end of original line (to which you anchor label), only draw further. So, if you like to anchor label to the end of the prolonged exes, you need to shift label for the same amount as you prolong line. See MWE below.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \centering
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \pgfplotsset{width=2.75in, height=2.75in,
                 clip=false,
                 axis lines=middle,
                 axis line style={latex-latex},
                 xtick={\empty},
                 xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style = {shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
       xlabel style = {at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},xshift=12.5pt,anchor=north west},
       ylabel style = {at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},yshift=12.5pt,anchor=south west},
        title style = {at={(0.5,-0.15)},anchor=north, font=\bfseries, align=center},  
                }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=axis_1, 
    xmin=-2.5,xmax=2.5,
    ymin=-15.625,ymax=15.625,
    restrict y to domain=-15.625:15.625,
    ytick={\empty},
%
       title = {An illustration of a function with \\
                no extrema},
                ]

\addplot[samples=251, domain=-2.5:2.5] {x^3)} 
    node[right, font=\footnotesize]{$y = x^{3}$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%
\hfill %qquad
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=axis_2, 
    xmin=-7.5,xmax=7.5, domain=-7:7,
    ymin=-1,ymax=1,
    restrict y to domain=-1:1,
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
    ytick={-1,1},
    yticklabels={$-1$, 1},
%
       title = {An illustration of a function with\\
                two extrema: $\boldmath -1$ and $\boldmath1$},
                ]
\addplot[samples=501, domain=-6.28318:6.28318] {sin(deg(x))} 
    node[anchor=south west, pos=0.6875,font=\footnotesize] {$y = \sin{x}$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In above code I make same changes which make it more concise. In this for title of graph I exploit `titlle` option of `pgfplotsset`.

Comment: @Adelyn, proposed solution might be convenient, but as far I see, it is more or less only possible, when you enlarge coordinate axes on such a way.